# GCP Datastream doesn't replicate new tables from RDS Postgres

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, amazon-rds, logical-replication, google-datastream

I have a datastream that replicate RDS postgres to Bigquery dataset.

Everything is set correctly, the datastream works. But we add new tables in RDS postgres and we don't see these new tables neither in the datastream nor in bigquery dataset.

We tried to add the new tables in publication, recreate publication, even recreate publication_slot but the new tables never showed up in bigquery.
I am expecting to see new tables in GCP datastream and finally in bigquery dataset.

Any ideas about how to handle new tables from RDS source to bigquery dataset ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

One possible explanation is that Datastream only "sees" a new table when the first CDC event occurs for that table. Are these new tables "active", i.e. are there new DML events (inserts/updates/deletes) in the tables?